# How to add a record to a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to create an control on embedded on a continuous form of which its activation event creates a new record on the form and inserts today's date in the date field.  I was thinking to use an SQL query to create the record but still am having difficulty.

Comment: It is important to post code when asking such questions. Look at default values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this...

In the table being inserted into, add a field called "date_entered" and have its default
value set to "Now()".   This will give you a timestamp (knowledge of when the record was entered).

Doing it this way is the easiest way, and then you don't have to write any extra code.